# setting up the same length of ValueAxis with jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am plotting several jfree charts in one window and want to align all chart.
All graph have the same range for x-axis and y-axis is displaying in the left.
However, when I am trying to set up fixed length for valuesAxis ,each graph still having different length of valueAxis.
There is extract of my code;

```
ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();

rangeAxis.setFixedDimension(40);
rangeAxis.setFixedAutoRange(40);
```

For time being I solved it by not displaying it at all

```
rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
```

Is these same way to set up the same length for all charts?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using either a `CombinedDomainXYPlot` or a `CombinedRangeXYPlot` to display your data; both will ensure the data area is the same size for all their subplots (AFAIK).

Comment: See also the combined axis demos among the `JFreeChart` [samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).